# Selenium error 'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element'

Tags: selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I get this error when trying to get the price of the product:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

But the thing is that I am searching by XPath from the Inspect HTML panel. SO how come it doesn't'search it?

Here is the code:

```
main_page = 'https://www.takealot.com/500-classic-family-computer-tv-game-ejc/PLID90448265'
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(main_page)
time.sleep(10)
active_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="shopfront-app"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/aside/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span').text
print(active_price)
```

I found the way to get the price the other way, but I am still interested why selenium can't find it by XPath:

```
price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'buybox-module_price_2YUFa').text

active_price = ''
after_discount = ''
count = 0

for char in price:
    if char == 'R':
        count +=1
    if count ==2:
        after_discount += char
    else:
        active_price += char

print(active_price)
print(after_discount)
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text ***R 345*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.takealot.com/500-classic-family-computer-tv-game-ejc/PLID90448265")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-ref='buybox-price-main']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.takealot.com/500-classic-family-computer-tv-game-ejc/PLID90448265")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-ref='buybox-price-main']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  R 345
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a price from buybox-module_price_2YUFa but price is actually inside the child span

```
//span[@data-ref='buybox-price-main']
```

Use following xpath to get the price